# Why does Eclipse not show a variable when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse

During development I don't want to initialize a boolean when it is declared since I need to make sure its value is set correctly later on and I therefore don't want it to have a default value.

The code looks like this:

```
Boolean newOffer;

//section A
try {
//section A.2
    newOffer = name.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("something");
} catch (Exception e){
    System.err.println(e);
}

//section B
try {
    newOffer = someTestThatReturnsABool();
    System.out.println("ok");
} catch (Exception e) {
    //section B.2
    System.out.println("not ok");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (newOffer) {
    doSomething();
}
```

At the comment `section A` - `newOffer` is not included in the list of active variables (`Window → Show view → Variables`). I guess that's fine since it isn't initialized (but still - it should be listed as *void*, *null* or something like that).

If the flow then goes via `section A.2` - `newOffer` is initialized, and it appears in the list of variables, which I think is expected. However, as soon as I step out of this `try-catch`-block, `newOffer` disappears from the variable list, just to reappear when `newOffer = someTestThatReturnsABool();` has been executed.

It is like I had declared it within the first `try-catch`-block, which I most definitely haven't, and it therefore is unassigned/GC or something when I leave that block.

**Is this just some weird Eclipse behaviour or is it expected? I would like to verify the value of `newOffer` on the line before `section B`. Can this be done if it is not listed in the variable list?**

I tried printing the value of `newOffer` just before `section B` but it doesn't compile since it might not be initialized (and you can't initialize `booleans` to `void`). I can print it section A.2 but that is pointless since when I am there it listed in the variable list anyway.

Comment: The JLS [Item 14.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2) tells you that if a variable declaration does not include an initializer, any reference to it must be preceded by an assignment. Basically, at the place where you want to know its value, it would be in violation of the spec to use its value. That code should not even compile.

Comment: "*but still - it should be listed as void, null or something like that*" Null would be wrong, since uninitialized is distinct from initialized to null.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yes, and it doesn't compile, but when it is initialized and assigned - why does it disappear from the variables view in Eclipse?

Comment: I don't understand the concept of initializing a variable in a program you cannot compile.

Comment: @RealSkeptic What do you mean? The program compiles as it is, but if I try to print out the value of the variable it doesn't compile.